# Webmin on Ubuntu 14.04 not listing AD users

Tags: ubuntu, samba, webmin

I have an Ubuntu Server 14.04 running Samba4 integrated with AD.  `wbinfo -u`, `wbinfo -g` all work fine.  I launch `webmin` on port 10000 and login.  I was able to create a file share one time, then assign permissions to a certain AD group.  after a reboot,  `webmin` is only showing local linux accounts and not AD accounts. very frustrating to not be able to add AD groups to file permissions.

[image: webmin not showing ad members]

I have tried to restart the webmin service as well as the server.  It worked before, now not showing the users.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though webmin is just configured to look at your local /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow rather than looking for AD accounts. Most likely this has to do with the PAM configuration in webmin.

http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Webmin_Configuration#Authentication